# Wallpaper change doesn't work after Intune Configuration Profile

Tags: powershell, windows-11, desktop-customization, intune

Currently we have the problem that we set the background images via Intune (Configuration Profiles). This unfortunately prevents the user from changing them themselves. Now we want to replace the configuration file with a PowerShell script that sets the background once and removes the limitation of Intune.

I have seen that I can delete the registry key under `HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PersonalizationCSP`, so the restriction of the user to set the image itself is removed.

Unfortunately, after that a reboot a different image is displayed. Which should not happen according to my research.

After that, I tried a script which runs in the user context and should change the wallpaper. The script works, but only after a reboot when I first deleted everything under `PersonalizationCSP`.

Can anyone recommend me an approach for removing the Intune limitation but also set a wallpaper for the user once?

Note: we are using Windows 11